# AS3 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method mnright

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have in frame 5, 10, 15, 20 I have `mnright();` I made a document class called Main and I declared the function `mnright();` in the main class and etc.. But when I try to run it I get 4 errors

> 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method mnright.

I've looked everywhere for an awnser but I cannot find one so this is my last resort.

Main.as

```
    package Main {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;

        public class Main extends MovieClip {

            public function Main() {
                trace("working");       

                function mnright():void {
                    if (man.hitTestObject(square)) {
                        pullBackwards();
                    } else {
                        man.x += 10;
                    }
                }

                function pullBackwards():void {
                    man.x -= 10;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to make `mnright()` and `pullBackwards()` public functions of your class. As it is they only exist within the constructor... so simply change to this :

```
package Main {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            trace("working");       

        }//end of constructor
        public function mnright():void {//becomes public member
            trace("mnright was used");
            if (man.hitTestObject(square)) {
                pullBackwards();
            } else {
                man.x += 10;
            }
        }
        public function pullBackwards():void {//this too
            trace("pulling backwards!");
            man.x -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, they could be private or protected, but for ease of use I recommend public, until you are more accustomed to document classes and their tricks :)